# Why do we need an expiration period?

Tags: linux, login, password

Why is there a gap between the **expiration** of an account and its complete **deactivation**, when one can no longer log in or change his password when it became expired?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained in the [venerable old Shadow Password HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Shadow-Password-HOWTO-7.html#ss7.2), between password expiration and the account's deactivation, the user *can* log in with the old password but must change it immediately. Or at least, that's the intention of the fields in the Linux "shadow password" system; specific implementations may not follow that strictly.

Comment: I accept your answer however I know it. my question is about those distros that make account inaccessible to the user once it became expired.

Comment: Those distros just aren't making use of that possibility in their default configurations.